# Ember.js ember-data findAll objects on the remote server

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, client-side, ember-data

Folks! Are there any examples of how ember-data and remote back-end server works together (separate applications - client-side with ember.js and abstractive back-end server, Rails for example)?
And the second question here - how to make array attribute (array of objects) with ember-data model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a guide on the Ember site, which provides a great explanation;

http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-models/

If you're using Rails you will probably be using the REST Adapter

http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/

This is a fully-functioning Ember app that uses ember-data and Rails:

https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example/

The last example may look like the application is integrated, but the client-side and back-end are completely separate. To change where the adapter expects to be sending data you can define a namespace and /or a url in your adapter:

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  url: "http://www.domain.com/path/to/remote_app/",
  namespace: "api/v1"
});
```

Comment: Somthing clear to me, thanks. Do I need after extending RESTAdapter write in the DS.model extend function smth like this: `url: 'resource' `?

Comment: no, the REST adapter will use the name of the resource to get the url (in a RESTful manner of course). You can change the configuration for individual models if you want, but better to keep the naming as close to the default as possible.